# How to rfkill unblock bluetooth ,airplane mode and more.?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, bluetooth, dell, rfkill

In my dell laptop i'm using Ubuntu. I turned  off airplane mode.But  automatically it will turned on device and bluetooth  also not working Wi-Fi mode is automatically disabled am I thinking this issue is only rfkill blocking all how to rfkill unblock all these.

Comment: Have you tried `rfkill unblock all`?

Comment: No i dont know how to to rfkill unblock all.  i did't get why its happened

Comment: Please runthis command `rfkill list` to see which is blocked

Comment: than how to unblock all

Comment: Run `rfkill unblock all` then `rfkill list` to be sure all was unblocked.

Comment: Been dealing with same issue for 6 months. Felt it was update related. Wake from sleep, or during use, network connection randomly disabled. Also noticed airplane mode and bluetooth directly correlated inverse of each other. Still without solution.